# Prisma raw query issue for UUID in WHERE IN

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I am trying to have UUID in WHERE IN in prisma in express js. but it's not working. Here is my code

```
const ids = ['r45545-2a554-458c-a94f-3ccd2f82582b','4fdgdgfdg-2f1b-4af5-81c8-3a29494a45f9'];

const datas =
        await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM public."myTable" 
      WHERE "id" IN (${ids.map(element => uuid('\''+element+'\'')).join(',')})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're trying to use a `uuid()` function in the template string that is not defined. You can simply remove the uuid() function and properly escape and join the UUID strings for the SQL query.

```js
const ids = ['r45545-2a554-458c-a94f-3ccd2f82582b', '4fdgdgfdg-2f1b-4af5-81c8-3a29494a45f9'];

const escapedIds = ids.map((id) => `'${id}'`).join(',');

const datas = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM public."myTable" WHERE "id" IN (${escapedIds})`;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . But it showing 'db error: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = text\n' +
      'HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.'

Comment: Here column datatype is UUID

Comment: You will need to cast text to uuid like this: `${Prisma.join(ids, ',', undefined, '::uuid')}`

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this issue by doing this approach.
instead of trying to cast your parameters, if you add ::text to your column, it will work.

```
const idsProdutos = Prisma.sql`and pf.cdproduto::text in (${Prisma.join(
  _produtos.map((produto) => produto.cdproduto)
)})`;
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar issue with my code. In my case, I had this line:

```
await prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(`UPDATE table SET "field" = "val" WHERE id = $1;`, id);
```

I fixed it by adding `::UUID` to my id field. This changes the line to:

```
await prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(`UPDATE table SET "field" = "val" WHERE id = $1::UUID;`, id);
```

In your case, I would try this:

```
const ids = ['r45545-2a554-458c-a94f-3ccd2f82582b','4fdgdgfdg-2f1b-4af5-81c8-3a29494a45f9'];
const idsCasted = ids.map(id => id + "::UUID");

const datas =
        await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM public."myTable" 
      WHERE "id" IN (${idsCasted.join(",")})`;
```